# How to convert hexadecimal slice to float with two's complement

Tags: go, type-conversion, hex

Is there any solution to convert hexdecimal slice to float64 value.
The slice is:
`bytes := []byte{0xD4,0x68,0x91,0x4A}`
Result float value must be `-731344566`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like that's a big endian int value. Use `encoding/binary` package:

```
    var v int32
    b := []byte{0xD4,0x68,0x91,0x4A}
    buf := bytes.NewReader(b)
    err := binary.Read(buf, binary.BigEndian, &v)
    f:=float64(v)
```